# Jquery mobile listview autodividersSelector

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been searching all over the web (and here), and can't seem to figure out what is going on. I have a jquery mobile (1.2) page with several items on a listview. I have added a custom attribute to each [li] tag and set that as the auto-divider according the the jquery mobile demo.

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="ScheduleDay">
<div data-role="header">
    <a href="#HomePage" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>      
    <h1 id="ScheduleDayText">Schedule</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" id="ScheduleList">
        <li time="3:30PM"><a href="#">Event 1</a></li>
        <li time="3:30PM"><a href="#">Event 2</a></li>
        <li time="4:30PM"><a href="#">Event 3</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#ScheduleList").listview({
autodividers: true,
autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
    var out = li.attr('time');]
    return out;
}
});
$('#ScheduleList').listview('refresh');
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pYYAu/7/) to show what I am trying to accomplish.

I can't seem to get the dividers to show up, and I am sure that I am overlooking something fairly minor (or completely missing the boat alltogether- I am still fairly new to jquery).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make it work:

1. Still need to use `data-autodividers="true"` on your `<ul>`
2. Put the code in the appropriate jQM handler `pageinit()` or `pagebeforeshow()`
3. There is a typo in `var out = li.attr('time');]` <-- you don't need the bracket at the end

That being said, your listview's markup will look like:

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="ScheduleList" data-autodividers="true">
</ul>
```

and JS code will look like:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#ScheduleDay", function(){
    $("#ScheduleList").listview({
        autodividers: true,
        autodividersSelector: function (li) {
            var out = li.attr("time");
            return out;
        }
    }).listview("refresh");
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/4fGT6/)

Comment: Thank you. One of these days i'll finally get the hang of jquery :)

Comment: @scholzr You're welcome. Do you need more help with the question?

Comment: No, thank you. I was able to work through the rest of the project based on what you gave me and some google searches.