# jquery mobile Autodividers in Listview with thumbnail

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, image, divider

I'd like to create a dynamic listview thanks to jquery mobile.
It works but if I put any thumbnail in the li of the listview there is no more auto dividers.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you show us some of your code, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the listview's autodividersSelector.

Have a look at: [Jquery mobile listview autodividersSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14743781/jquery-mobile-listview-autodividersselector)